# Jquery function not working in client side in MVC4

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I used the following code

```
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Run" onclick="RunEXE()" />


<script type="text/javascript">
function RunEXE() {

    $.post('@Url.Action("Compile", "Compile")',
        {
            fileName: $("#FileName").val(),
            programCode: $("#ProgramCode").val(),
            compileOutput: $("#CompileOutput").val(),
            language: "C",
            button: "Run"
        },
        function(data) {
            var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            var prog = "\\\\Test-PC\\Programms\\Ramkumar\\"+data.MyString+".exe";
            oShell.Run('"' + prog + '"', 1);
        }
    );
}
```

When i use the above code the jquery is working upto `var prog = "\\\\Test-PC\\Programms\\Ramkumar\\"+data.MyString+".exe";` After that nothing happpen. But when we are not calling the server side function from jquery, it works fine.

Comment: This should *never* work from an http request.

Answer (score 1):

Javascripts runs on client machine and **browser does not allow you to run exe on client machine** for client machine security. If you want to run some *exe* on server side then send a `ajax call` on server indication for running exe  through `c#` code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **preventDefault()** to the end of the function as you are handling the onclick on a submit button.

Or

Try to change the

```
<input type="submit"> to <input type="button">
```

Edited:

```
function RunEXE() {

$.post('@Url.Action("Compile", "Compile")',
    {
        fileName: $("#FileName").val(),
        programCode: $("#ProgramCode").val(),
        compileOutput: $("#CompileOutput").val(),
        language: "C",
        button: "Run"
    },
    function(data) {
        var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        var prog = "\\\\Test-PC\\Programms\\Ramkumar\\"+data.MyString+".exe";
        oShell.Run('"' + prog + '"', 1);
    }        
);
return false; // equivalent to preventDefault() in JQuery
}
```

Comment: Where to add preventDefault() just copy my code above and show me